# Firefox SDK: Destroy a widget

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I want to show an widget only on websites the URL is matching my expression. So if it does, it creates an widget, if it doesn't it should destroy it (if it's existing)

So I tried this:

```
 var Widget = require("widget").Widget;
 var view = Widget.getView(tabs.window);

 if(!view && check) {    
             var wig = new Widget({

                        id: "downloadbutton",
                        //other elements
                    });

            } else if(view && !check) { 
                view.destroy(downloadbutton);

            }
```

The console tells me that getView were not a function! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to store the return value of `new Widget` in `view`, then invoke `getView` on this instance.

Comment: And how do I do it before? If I don't even know if the widgets were created?

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/widget.html#attach